# Let's steer clear of [Navigation]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[navigation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/navigation) is currently undefined.  It is not necessarily a bad tag.  The vast majority of questions relate to moving around in the user environment of the computer.  There are a few exceptions.  Some deal with navigation in the geographic sense and some are just irrelevant uses of the tag.

I submitted a tag wiki edit to define the tag as relating to the computer environment and recommending use of the [geolocation] tag for the other usage.  I think that would be an adequate fix, along with modifying the exception tags and deleting the irrelevant usage.  I tried deleting the irrelevant tags but the system won't allow an edit that does not include at least a certain number of characters in the question, itself.

Comment: Tempted to edit title to "Steer clear of [tag:navigation]"

Comment: OOOOOOH! I like that.  Do it!  Do it!

Comment: "navigation" and "geolocation" are two different things.

Comment: @Brad - I was trying to differentiate navigation within the computer environment from questions that used the navigation tag in the geographic sense.  Some of those actually related to geolocation and navigation was a bad tag selection.  Can you recommend an appropriate tag for geographic navigation?  Should the current tag be changed to something different for navigating the computer environment?

Comment: @fixer1234 Would `geographic-navigation` and `ui-navigation` come up as suggested tags should someone type in `navigation`?

Comment: @Brad - cyber-navigation?